# MVC, Updating a Model, Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view, model and a controller, I want the user to start editing the page of a new contact.

They will

1. Enter the First and Last Name
2. Click Save
3. The Controller commits the save.
4. Expand the page to Show display name for editing.

In forms Asp.net I stick the Primary Key of the Saved record in the view state so on the next save, I do an update vs. an Insert.

How do I do that in MVC, Razor?  I have seen examples using a Hidden Field but I would think there is a better way.  I would prefer it not shown at all, or at least encrypted but I do not want to build the encryption or decryption routines.

Comment: Its a good start to go through the tutorials on this site, what you asking for is basics in MVC, http://www.asp.net/mvc

Answer (score 0):

User `HiddenFor()` method of Html helper class. `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)`. By the way, ViewState is stored in a hidden field in ASP.NET.

If you are really wanting to encrypt the data like in viewState, you can use `Html.Serialize()`method which serializes and encrypts entire model in view and you will then have to De-serialize it in the controller after it's posted. Have a look at this [article](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/10/08/Leveraging-ASPNET-MVC-2-futures-ViewState.aspx)

Comment: Neither ViewState or Serialize encrypts the data.  It Encodes it.  There is a difference.  Encryption requires a key.  By the way, Serialize is not part of MVC, you have to install the MVC Futures project to get it.